# Beam running on flink with python sdk and using google cloud storage for artifacts directory

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

( I tried sending this to the apache mailing list, but for some odd reason, it won't go through )
I'm trying to set up beam running on flink with python sdk locally using docker.
Currently, I just have a single flink job manager in a docker container, and a single flink task manager in a docker container with the beam job server running on the job manager container.
The pipeline options are as follows:

```
PipelineOptions([
"--runner=PortableRunner",
"--environment_type=PROCESS",
"--environment_config={\"command\": \"/beam_src_code/sdks/python/container/build/target/launcher/linux_amd64/boot\"}",
"--job_endpoint=localhost:8099"])
```

And the job server is ran as follows with artifacts directory in gcs:
java -jar jar_lib/beam-runners-flink-1.8-job-server-2.16.0.jar --flink-master-url localhost:8081 --artifacts-dir gs:///matthew_magsombol/ --job-port 8099
The behavior is that the job gets submitted to the flink cluster, but it freezes up and eventually runs into an illegal state and throwing an exception.

Flink Jobmanager Logs:

```
    java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkExecutableStageFunction.open(FlinkExecutableStageFunction.java:130)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:494)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:163)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 15 more
    2019-12-20 16:55:24,726 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job BeamApp-flink-1220165317-c558fc1d (f7a4b06e1ca475f4b935b84dc0c8e186) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
    java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkExecutableStageFunction.open(FlinkExecutableStageFunction.java:130)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:494)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:163)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 15 more
```

Flink taskmanager logs:

```
    2019-12-20 17:01:33,095 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask                  - Error in task code:  CHAIN MapPartition (MapPartition at [2]write/Write/WriteImpl/DoOnce/{FlatMap(<lambda at core.py:2468>), Map(decode)}) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at ExtractOutput[0]) (1/1)
    java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkExecutableStageFunction.open(FlinkExecutableStageFunction.java:130)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:494)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:163)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 15 more
    2019-12-20 17:01:33,095 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask                  - Error in task code:  CHAIN MapPartition (MapPartition at [1]read/Read/Split) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at ExtractOutput[0]) (1/1)
    java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkExecutableStageFunction.open(FlinkExecutableStageFunction.java:130)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:494)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:163)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 15 more
    2019-12-20 17:01:33,097 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - CHAIN MapPartition (MapPartition at [2]write/Write/WriteImpl/DoOnce/{FlatMap(<lambda at core.py:2468>), Map(decode)}) -> FlatMap (FlatMap at ExtractOutput[0]) (1/1) (2a610de72b94e612a977136c7381e6e2) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
    java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkExecutableStageFunction.open(FlinkExecutableStageFunction.java:130)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:494)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:163)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 15 more
```

Beam Jobserver logs:

```
    [flink-runner-job-invoker] ERROR org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.jobsubmission.JobInvocation - Error during job invocation BeamApp-flink-1220165928-dbc405d9_f898fc97-9a7c-4f6a-988f-8ee74bd7b9a7.
    org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed. (JobID: 50c07fcc2f2b1dde3a7073f430e4aa50)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:268)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:483)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:471)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:446)
        at org.apache.flink.client.RemoteExecutor.executePlanWithJars(RemoteExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.flink.client.RemoteExecutor.executePlan(RemoteExecutor.java:187)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.RemoteEnvironment.execute(RemoteEnvironment.java:173)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPortablePipelineTranslator$BatchTranslationContext.execute(FlinkBatchPortablePipelineTranslator.java:191)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineRunner.runPipelineWithTranslator(FlinkPipelineRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineRunner.run(FlinkPipelineRunner.java:80)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.jobsubmission.JobInvocation.runPipeline(JobInvocation.java:78)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:265)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:212)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:186)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultExecutableStageContext.getStageBundleFactory(DefaultExecutableStageContext.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory$WrappedContext.getStageBundleFactory(ReferenceCountingExecutableStageContextFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkExecutableStageFunction.open(FlinkExecutableStageFunction.java:130)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:494)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 1
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:163)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 15 more
    Dec 20, 2019 5:01:33 PM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
    WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
    [flink-runner-job-invoker] INFO org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.BeamFileSystemArtifactRetrievalService - Manifest at gs://<gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/MANIFEST has 1 artifact locations
    [pool-11-thread-1] INFO org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil - Ignoring failed deletion of file gs://<gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/artifacts/ which already does not exist: {"code":404,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"No such object: <gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/artifacts/","reason":"notFound"}],"message":"No such object: <gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/artifacts/"}
    [pool-13-thread-1] INFO org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil - Ignoring failed deletion of file gs://<gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/ which already does not exist: {"code":404,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"No such object: <gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/","reason":"notFound"}],"message":"No such object: <gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/"}
    [flink-runner-job-invoker] INFO org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.BeamFileSystemArtifactStagingService - Removed dir gs://<gcs_location>/matthew_magsombol/job_53b08ce8-cec3-4a39-ae60-95398eb04b43/
```

Midway through the run, I've confirmed that the beam job server IS able to create a job directory in the gcs location ( it does auto delete when the run ends ).
( My previous attempts at this, the error led me to an authentication issue with gcs, and that was mainly due to gcp creds not being accessible by flink job manager and flink task manager...already fixed it, so it is no longer spitting that error out...so I don't think this might be a gcp credentials issue?)
I've followed most of Yu Watanabe's email threads: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/2ca72cb1946f428aabeb2b8573ba8e3270bbf34b97107c53d26fbf76%40%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E ( with a slight difference in artifact directory ).

Thanks!

Comment: Before you can post to the mailing list, you have to be subscribed to it. (https://flink.apache.org/community.html#how-to-subscribe-to-a-mailing-list)

Comment: Ah gotcha, let me do that, thanks!

Comment: Same problem here.  Mine fails every other run.  Maybe Flink is round-robin distributing or something.  My setup is a bit different as I'm not running boot.go in a container.  Also notice that the error mentions LocalCache.  Since /tmp is on a node's drive, maybe change it to a shared location???

Comment: @RobertLugg So I got mine to run. I ran the flink cluster in debug mode and basically the beam python code was written in python3 and ran as python3 which is submitted to the beam job server which will submit to the artifacts directory ( I pointed mine to google cloud storage since I need a shared directory...hdfs works too ). The flink cluster will then pick up this artifact but run it as python2. I pointed the default to python3 and it turned out fine.

Comment: So for yours, if you want to run it in docker, you'll have to create a shared volume since they're using that as a place to put the artifacts that the beam job server is pushing....
( For production, if we decide to use it, I'll most likely use google cloud storage...just how I'm doing now, or maybe aws s3, whichever works )

For reference, take a look at this:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z3LNrRtr8kkiFHonZ5JJM_L4NWNBBNcqRc_yAf6G0VI/edit#heading=h.x9qy4wlfgc1g
Most likely, your staging location is not accessible by all the workers...I'm not sure if that's the reason, only a hunch.

Comment: @MatthewMagsombol You are right on.  I am starting the job server using gradlew and without specifying an artifactDir.  After specifying a shared directory, things seem to be working.